# Nodes effect not coming after exporting in .glb

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, export

I am new to Blender and am only using it for a few hours to quickly create and export a 3D Model in .glb format to use it in my React website project with three js.

I have applied certain Nodes in the Material of a cube, which are 'Texture Coordinate', 'Mapping', 'Gradient Texture', 'Color Ramp', Principled BSDF', and 'Material Output'. These are used to create a gradient on the surface of my cube. However, when I export my model, these Nodes are not applied and the gradient is lost, even though I clicked on 'Apply' to apply the material on this cube. I am sorry if my terms are all over the place since I am new. Nevertheless, I have attached photos to help you understand better[image].

Thank you and cheers!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures). By the way, the _Apply_ button in the _Material Properties_ is to apply a selected material (you can have multiple materials on an object) to a selection of faces.